# Django Admin: how to display a url as a link while calling specific function to download the file

Tags: django, django-admin

Title is a bit confusing, but basically I have an s3 path stored as a string

```
class S3Stuff(Model):
    s3_path = CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    # rest is not important
```

There are existing methods to download the content given the url, so I want to utilize that

```
def download_from_s3(bucket, file_name):
    s3_client = boto3.client(bleh_bleh)
    s3_response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=file_name)
    return {'response': 200, 'body': s3_response['Body'].read()}
```

`s3_path` can be broken into `bucket` and `file_name`. This works very easily when I use my own frontend because I can do whatever I want with it, but I don't know how to apply this to admin

```
class S3StuffAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = S3Stuff
    fields = ('s3_path', )
```

Now how do I call that method and make the display a link that says "download"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this function will be much useful for generating download links, instead use the boto3's [**`presigned_url`**](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html) like this:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html


class S3StuffAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = S3Stuff
    fields = ('s3_path', )
    readonly_field = ('download',)

    def download(self, obj):
       s3_client = boto3.client(bleh_bleh)
       url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Key': obj.s3_path}, ExpiresIn = 100)
       return format_html('<a href={}>download</a>'.format(url))
```

Comment: Yes! I figured that I should be using a url with `mark_safe` function. It works perfectly!